# How to rebuild a library project

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I'm still somewhat of a novice with Xcode. I have added a third party open source project to my project. I have added it to my target dependencies, and have added the lib ".a" file to "Link Binary With Libraries." Everything works fine as far as that goes.

However, I discovered an error in the source code of this project. Now that I have corrected this error, how do I rebuild this project so that I can access this new, changed code from my project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is linked properly to this open source library, any changes made to the source files of that library will be recognized by your project. So, in short, just build as usual.